# Adaptar script en Perl para windows

Tags: windows, perl

Necesitaría ayuda con un script que no acabo de entender muy bien como funciona y que me parece que habría que adaptar para poder ejecutarlo en Windows (mi sistema operativo).

El **script** es el siguiente:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

#------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This code is open-source as defined by the GPL, 2002
# by Willie Northway - http://www.willienorthway.com/
# http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
# $Id: clam_covers.pl,v 1.8 2003/04/15 14:08:45 willn Exp $ 
#
# Note: I've noticed some problems in Mac OS X when trying to read
# the pdf from a UFS drive. It reports "Macintosh system error
# (-39)" This is a eofErr - End of File Error. These seem to be readable
# from an HFS+ partition though.
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

my ($path) = shift;
my (@Data, @Temp);
my ($entry, $file, $line, $query, $grabbed, $data, $datafile, $name);
my ($debug) = 0;

if ($path) { $data = $path; } 
else
{
$data = "./data/";
$datafile = 1;
}

if (opendir (DIR, $data))
{
if ($datafile)  #read individual data files
{
    foreach $entry (sort (readdir (DIR)))
    {
        $file = $data.$entry;

        if (( $entry =~ /^\./ ) || ( $entry =~ /^Desktop D\w/ )) { ; }
        elsif ($datafile)
        {
            if (open (INDATA, "$file"))
            {
                @Data = <INDATA>;
                close (INDATA);
                chomp (@Data);

                $query = ProcessAlbum( $entry, 1, @Data );

                if (!$debug) { `$query`; }
                else { print "Q: $query\n\n"; }
            }
            else { print "Couldn't open data file: $file, $!\n"; }
        }
    }

  }
  else          #read from CD directory
  {
    foreach $entry (sort (readdir (DIR)))
    {
        if (( $entry =~ /^\./ ) || ( $entry =~ /^Desktop D\w/ )) { ; }
        elsif (-d $data.$entry) 
        {
            if (opendir (DIR2, $data.$entry))
            {
                foreach $name (sort (readdir (DIR2)))
                { if ( $name !~ /^\./ ) { push (@Data, "$entry - $name");        } }
                close( DIR2 );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $entry =~ s/'//;
            $entry =~ s/\.aiff$//;
            push (@Data, $entry);
        }
    }

    @Temp = split /\//, $data;
    while (!$data && $#Temp) { $data = pop (@Temp); }

    $data =~ s/^.*\/([^\/]+)\/?$/$1/;
    $query = ProcessAlbum( $data, 0, @Data );

    if (!$debug) { `$query`; }
    else { print "Q: $query\n\n"; }
   }

   }
   else { print "Couldn't open data directory: $!\n"; }

   sub Numerically { $a <=> $b; }

  sub ProcessAlbum
{
my ($title, $fromfile, @Tracks) = @_;
my ($request, $line_num) = 0;

$title =~ s/ /_/g;

$request = "wget 'http://papercdcase.com/papercdcase.cgi/".
    "papercdcase.pdf?artist=$title";

if ( !$fromfile ) { @Tracks = sort Numerically( @Tracks ); }
foreach $line ( @Tracks )
{
    $line = CleanName ($line);
    $line_num++;
    $request .= "&track".$line_num."=$line";
}
$request .= "&template=jewel&size=letter&lang=western".
"&submit.x=0&submit.y=0' --output-document=$title.pdf";

print "\nREQ: $request\n\n";
return $request;
}


sub CleanName
{
my ($line) = @_;

$line =~ s/\+/%2B/g;
$line =~ s/ /+/g;
$line =~ s/&/%26/g;
$line =~ s/'/%27/g;
$line =~ s/#/%23/g;

return $line;
}
```

Comment: Solo quieres correrlo en windows?

Comment: Si. A ver, he visto que utiliza Wget, que no es una aplicación de Windows, y me he bajado los binarios de Windows de la aplicación. Pero sigo sin comprender muy bien la función del script, que de todas formas no me funciona.

Comment: Que error te esta dando?

Comment: Un mensaje como que no se encuentra el archivo o directorio. Pero es que de entrada desconozco el argumento que tengo que poner detrás de clam_covers.pl. Yo he probado clam_covers.pl "%CD%" que parece leer los contenidos del directorio actual.

Comment: Ya revisando el código espera una ruta con un archivo que va inspeccionar lo voy probar. Pero que esperas hacer con el script?

Comment: Yo utilizo habitualmente paper cd case:

Comment: Yo utilizo habitualmente paper cd case: http://www.papercdcase.com/ que crea un PDF de carátulas recortables para CD.
Lo que yo quiero es poder hacerlo desde mi PC sin tener que depender necesariamente de la página web. Es decir, tener un programa que lo haga y que no dependa de conexión a Internet.
En http://www.papercdcase.com/about.php ellos mencionan este script de un tal Willie Northway que me he bajado que dicen "Perl script than converts a text file to a PaperCDCase PDF file."

Comment: He probado clam_covers.pl "Nuevo documento de texto.txt" y no funciona.

Comment: Revisando el script ya viste esta linea  if (( $entry =~ /^\./ ) || ( $entry =~ /^Desktop D\w/ )) { ; } Nunca encuentra esta carpeta

Comment: ¿Sabrías como solucionarlo? Yo la verdad es que el lenguaje Perl no lo entiendo y no se que se puede editar en el script o no.

Comment: Si se puede editar solo dejame hacer unas pruebas y te lo subo

Answer (score 0):

He hecho un par de modificaciones al script y al menos he conseguido hacerlo funcionar, aunque mal.
Nota: Hay que tener la aplicación wget.exe en la variable PATH

A estas dos líneas les he quitado el apóstrofo y a la segunda le he sustituido $title.pdf por papercdcase.pdf:

Original:
$request = "wget 'http://papercdcase.com/papercdcase.cgi/".
"&submit.x=0&submit.y=0' --output-document=$title.pdf";

Modificado:
$request = "wget http://papercdcase.com/papercdcase.cgi/".
"&submit.x=0&submit.y=0 --output-document=papercdcase.pdf";

Supongo que el programa espera como argumento la ruta de un directorio, aunque esto no lo tengo claro.
Desde la línea de comandos en el símbolo del sistema ejecuto: clam_covers.pl "%USERPROFILE%\Music\Ennio Morricone\A Fistful Of Dollars"

Esto crea un PDF (de carátulas) como se pretende, pero queda mal. Además el directorio parece que no puede tener subdirectorios.